# pointer-events: none allow scroll but disable click-JS/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way where setting `pointer-events: none` can only disable the click on that container but have scroll enable on the same with an overlay.

I have fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/1eu6d3sq/1/

When I mask, using `pointer-events: none`, the entire container disables and when I remove this property- all events get enabled.
css:

```
   .parent {
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none; /* if I remove this the scrolling works and click is also enabled. if I add this, scrolling and click both get disabled */
}
    
.button {cursor: pointer}
.main {    
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
}
    
.mask {
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="parent"><div class="main">

      <div class="aaaa">
      Some masked contentThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above
      </div>
      <div>This is some text covered by the mask</div>
      <div>
      <span onclick="function hi(){alert('Hi!')};hi()">clicked SAPN</span>
      </div>
      <button class="button">
         <span class="span-button">OK</span>
      </button>
      <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);">
        <div>
            <div>
              Some contents above the mask
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If I understand `pointer-events` property correctly, it will disable all events triggered.
Here I have added `pointer-events` to my parent/root element and all subsequent elements inside that parent gets disabled. however how can I make the parent/root DOM element listen only to scroll element?

I tried:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", this.onBodyScroll, true);
```

but `onBodyScroll` function never gets triggered.

any ideas?

Comment: The only scrollable content I can see in your fiddle is the `.aaaa` element, not the document - is that what you meant?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: Sorry Yes, I meant the root container. I updated my desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) documentation on `pointer-events`

> Note that preventing an element from being the target of pointer events by using pointer-events does not necessarily mean that pointer event listeners on that element cannot or will not be triggered. If one of the element's children has pointer-events explicitly set to allow that child to be the target of pointer events, then any events targeting that child will pass through the parent as the event travels along the parent chain, and trigger event listeners on the parent as appropriate. Of course any pointer activity at a point on the screen that is covered by the parent but not by the child will not be caught by either the child or the parent (it will go "through" the parent and target whatever is underneath).

Keeping this in mind, re-setting `pointer-events` on your overflow container should enable scrolling while all other events disabled. (Forgetting `mask`)

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  /* if I remove this the scrolling works and click is also enabled. if I add this, scrolling and click both get disabled */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer
}

.aaaa {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
}


/* .mask {
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100%;
} */
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aaaa">
    Some masked contentThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents above
  </div>
  <div>This is some text covered by the mask</div>
  <div>
    <span onclick="function hi(){alert('Hi!')};hi()">clicked SAPN</span>
  </div>
  <button class="button">
           <span class="span-button">OK</span>
        </button>
  <!-- <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);">
          <div>
              <div>
                Some contents above the mask
              </div>
          </div>
        </div> -->
</div>
```

Now if you want to `mask`, you don't really have to set any `pointer-events`. It should work as intended(click disabled and scroll enabled).

```css
.main {
  position: relative;
  /* if I remove this the scrolling works and click is also enabled. if I add this, scrolling and click both get disabled */
  pointer-events: none;
}

.button {
  cursor: pointer
}

.aaaa {
  height: 80px;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.mask {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: default;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="aaaa">
    Some masked contentThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents aboveThis is some text covered by the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome contents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome ontents above the maskSome
    ontents above
  </div>
  <div>This is some text covered by the mask</div>
  <div>
    <span onclick="function hi(){alert('Hi!')};hi()">clicked SAPN</span>
  </div>
  <button class="button">
            <span class="span-button">OK</span>
        </button>
  <div class="mask" style="background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);">
    <div>
      <div>
        Some contents above the mask
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @first, thanks for the detailed descp- I tried here in https://jsfiddle.net/1eu6d3sq/2/. all my content is inside a container masked entirely- the ```pointer-events: auto``` makes  ```<span>``` clickable. what im i missing? sorry if I missed explaining rightly before

Comment: As now all your content is residing inside the overflow container and you want to scroll it anyway, so applying `pointer-events` on it doesn't matter. All you can do is remove all the `pointer-events` from your styles and do `.main * {pointer-events: none;}` so any child element with trigger events is disabled (and you can always enable it back for any specific element with `pointer-events: auto` i.e. for `OK` button `.span-button {pointer-events: auto;}`). Hope this helps.